# Im trying to calculate the formula of a sphere using cpp

Tags: c++

Im making a calculator that can code the volume of a sphere, but i cant make the formula without getting the wrong answer. *volume of sphere is 4/3 pi r cubed*. And cant figure out how to make a fraction without making a complex function. Any idea on how to write out the formula correctly?

```
    }else if (volumeChoice == "sphere"){
        double sphereRadius { 0 };
        const double pi { 3.14159265358979323846 };
        cout << "Enter the radius\n";
        cin >> sphereRadius;
        double sphereFormula { (4/3) pi * pow(3.0, sphereRadius)};
        cout << sphereFormula;
```

Comment: `4/3` is an *integer* division, with an *integer* result.

Comment: Also, you can't have implied multiplication (like `(4/3) pi`) in C++, all multiplication must be explicit (using `*`).

Comment: And in the future, please actually tell us what problems you have with the code you show. And ask an actual question. Please take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: And it should the be "the radius, cubed", not "three to the power of the radius".

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple main issues I noticed.

One: `4/3` uses integer division in C++, so the result returns 1, not 1.3333...
Change it to `4.0/3.0`

Two: There is no multiplication sign between the `4/3` and pi, so it shouldn't compile.

Three: The `pow` function first parameter is the base, and the second is the exponent. The call should be `pow(sphereRadius, 3.0)` not `pow(3.0, sphereRadius)`

The line after changes should look like the following:

```cpp
double sphereFormula { (4.0/3.0) * pi * pow(sphereRadius, 3.0)};
```

Answer (score 1):

`4 / 3` is integer division (result is 1), and your result will not be accurate because of that. Change it to `4.0 / 3.0` and you should see better results.

I'd be surprised if this code compiles because you're missing a multiplication sign between your four thirds and pi.

Finally, your arguments to `pow()` are switched. The first argument is the base, the second is the exponent. It never hurts to refer to [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow).

```cpp
double sphereFormula{(4.0 / 3.0) * pi * pow(sphereRadius, 3.0)};
```

A touch more explanation:
C++ reads natural number literals (4 and 3 in your case) as integers. Placing a `.0` causes the compiler to read the literal as a double. C++ is not like python or other languages that will produce a decimal result from integer division.

Comment: so when i put 2 as the radius, i got 37.6691 but the real answer is 33.51032. And i made the changes as you stated

Comment: I'ved edited in another fix regarding `pow()`.

Comment: oh thank you for telling me about pow() it works now, thank you!